# Get authenticated user in laravel 5.3 controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get `Auth::user()` in controller of Laravel 5.3 but it shows `null` everytime. Is this changed in Laravel 5.3?

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ url('/user/login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/user/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
        {{ Auth::user()}}
    </a>
```

Its going everytime in if condition even if I am logged in

Comment: Please share us the latest code. Thanks

Comment: Is the user logged in?

Comment: yes user is logged in

Comment: Please share your code so that we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

first of all yes it changes; in 5.2 Authenticate file was on app/Http/Middleware but know its change to vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth
now i had same problem like you and because my project was 5.2 i get confuse but you can also make your own authenticate file on app/Http/Middleware 
its works for me 
I hope my answer be useful for you

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you please share your authenticate. php file code? and did you make any changes on kernel.php? or any other changes?

Comment: Hi This is my Authenticate.php:                                                                                  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    } also i change my Kernel to:  'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely not a very "laravel-way" but a workaround for that is defining a middleware and passing in a closure in the constructor method.

```
public function __construct()
{   
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

from then you can use `$this->user` in your other methods.
It works, but I'm not sure how proper of a solution that is. If someone knows a better way, I'm also looking for it :)